# Is there an apple passport strategy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js

Like there is a [passport-facebook](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-facebook/) strategy and a [passport-google-oauth20](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-google-oauth20/) strategy, is there an apple strategy?

I have searched for an apple equivalent but I have not found one apart from this npn package [passport-apple](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-apple). However, this package only has 2,808 weekly downloads so I'm not sure I feel comfortable using it.

If there isn't a passport strategy for apple, what are some alternative options aside from the passport-apple npm package?

If possible can you also please link to some form of implementation of said alternatives?

Comment: https://github.com/ananay/passport-apple

Answer (score 1):

I'm the creator of passport-apple.

This is a fully working passport strategy for Sign in with Apple, and if you need help, I've deployed a working example on this repository: https://github.com/ananay/passport-apple-example

Please feel free to reach out to me on Twitter if you need help!

All the best.

Comment: Hi Ananay, I'm glad you are the creator passport-apple. I was using passport-apple for apple login in nestjs and there was no id_teken in my payload. Only code, state and perhaps user. I tried all the help I could get on the internet, none solve the problem. Until I uninstalled passport-apple and use  @arendajaelu/nestjs-passport-apple and it solved my problems. So why is passport-apple not designed to return id_token?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75494769/signin-with-apple-with-passport-apple-library-not-returning-id-token-in-nestjs